# how to add pip to PATH

Tags: windows-10, python

I installed Python using the "Windows x86-64 executable installer" from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-383/ . That, however, did not modify the Windows Path variable so I decided to modify it myself.

The python executable lives here:

C:\Users\neubert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\

But there is no pip executable in that directory. It's my understanding that "Windows x86-64 executable installer" was supposed to include pip. So where is it?

Here's the directory listing of this directory:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        6/10/2020   7:54 AM                DLLs
d-----        6/10/2020   7:53 AM                Doc
d-----        6/10/2020   7:53 AM                include
d-----        6/10/2020   7:53 AM                Lib
d-----        6/10/2020   7:53 AM                libs
d-----        6/10/2020   7:54 AM                Scripts
d-----        6/10/2020   7:54 AM                tcl
d-----        6/10/2020   7:53 AM                Tools
-a----        5/13/2020  10:43 PM          31453 LICENSE.txt
-a----        5/13/2020  10:43 PM         905782 NEWS.txt
-a----        5/13/2020  10:42 PM         100424 python.exe
-a----        5/13/2020  10:42 PM          58952 python3.dll
-a----        5/13/2020  10:42 PM        4208200 python38.dll
-a----        5/13/2020  10:42 PM          98888 pythonw.exe
-a----        5/13/2020  10:43 PM         100880 vcruntime140.dll
-a----        5/13/2020  10:43 PM          44320 vcruntime140_1.dll
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It does not mention pip on the page you linked.

Comment: @DavidPostill - the installer mentions it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Qqv.png

Comment: OK. Then I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So where is `pip`?

Assuming you chose the option to install `pip` via the installer, `pip.exe` should be located under the `Scripts` directory:

*ex. Python/Scripts*

[image: pip.exe - Python Scripts Directory - Screenshot]

So you should be able to add ex.:

```
 C:\Users\neubert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts
```

to your environment variables if you want to allow access to the executables in `Scripts` globally via the command line.

*However, while adding the `Scripts` directory to your Windows environment is useful (and I would recommend you do this for potential access to other exectuables created by Python), I would recommend NOT accessing `pip` like this.*

Instead, you should use `python -m pip` in place of just `pip`. In short, this can help avoid possible headaches with "missing" modules when more than one copy of Python is installed on Windows (ex. if you need to use a copy of Python in a Python virtual environment for an isolated project).

Answer (score 0):

neubert:

Did you try in set path from the command line (cmd)?

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\neubert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
```